# ngrx store select giving undefined always

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am new to Angular 6 I am trying to get data using ngrx store select.

**shoppingcart.model.ts**

```js
export class Cart {
  ShoppingCart: ShoppingCart;
  Callbacks: Callbacks;
}
export class Callbacks {
  CallbackURL: string;
  CallbackURLInEmail: string;

  constructor() {
    this.CallbackURL = undefined;
    this.CallbackURLInEmail = undefined;
  }
}

export class ShoppingCartTotal {
  Amount: Amount;
  Currency: string;
  NumberofItems: NumberofItems;
}

export class ShoppingCart {
  ShoppingCartTotal: ShoppingCartTotal;
  ShoppingCartItems: ShoppingCartItems;

  constructor() {
    this.ServiceFees = undefined;
    this.ShoppingCartTotal = undefined;
  }
}
export class ShoppingCartItem {
  Type: string;
  PassengerID: PassengerID;
  ShoppingCartItemID: ShoppingCartItemID;
  Quantity: Quantity;
}
```

**action.ts**

```js
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Cart } from '@app/shared/models';

export enum ShoppingCartActionTypes {
  SHOPPINGCART_DEFAULT = '[Cart] Load Default Shopping Cart',
  SHOPPINGCART_ADD = '[Cart] Add Shopping Cart',
  SHOPPINGCART_UPDATE = '[Cart] Update Shopping Cart',
  SHOPPINGCART_DELETE = '[Cart] Delete Shopping Cart'
}

export class DeleteCartAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_DELETE;
  constructor(public payload?: any) {}
}

export class LoadCartDefaultAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_DEFAULT;
  constructor(public payload?: Cart) {}
}
export class LoadCartAddAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_ADD;
  constructor(public payload?: Cart) {}
}

export class UpdateCartAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_UPDATE;
  constructor(public payload: Cart) {}
}

export type ShoppingCartActionsUnion =
  | LoadCartDefaultAction
  | UpdateCartAction
  | LoadCartAddAction
  | DeleteCartAction;
```

**Reducer.ts**

```js
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import {
  ShoppingCartActionTypes,
  ShoppingCartActionsUnion
} from '../actions/createshoppingcart.actions';
import { Cart } from '@app/shared/models';

export interface CartState {
  Cart: Cart;
}

export const initialState: CartState = {
  Cart: new Cart()
};

export function Cartreducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ShoppingCartActionsUnion
): CartState {
  let update = getClone(state.Cart);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_DEFAULT: {
      return initialState;
    }
    case ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_UPDATE: {
      update = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        Cart: action.payload
      };
    }
    case ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_DELETE: {
      return initialState;
    }

    case ShoppingCartActionTypes.SHOPPINGCART_ADD: {
      return {
        ...state,
        Cart: action.payload
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export function getClone(trip: Cart): Cart {
  let clone = cloneDeep(trip);
  return clone;
}
```

**Index.ts**

```js
import {
  ActionReducerMap,
  combineReducers,
  compose,
  createSelector,
  createFeatureSelector,
  ActionReducer,
  MetaReducer
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import * as shoppingCartreducer from './createshoppingcart.reducer';
import * as fromRouter from '@ngrx/router-store';

export interface State {
  shoppingCart: shoppingCartreducer.CartState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  shoppingCart: shoppingCartreducer.Cartreducer
};
```

**state.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Cartreducer, CartState } from './reducers/createshoppingcart.reducer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({ categories: Cartreducer })],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppStateModule {}
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from '../backend/api/api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Cart } from 'app/shared/models';
import * as shoppingCartAction from 'app/state/actions/createshoppingcart.actions';
import * as fromRoot from '@app/state/reducers';
import { CartState } from '@app/state/reducers/createshoppingcart.reducer';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [APIService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  testData: any;
  // testData: Observable<any>;
  constructor(
    private apiService: APIService,
    private store: Store<CartState>
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfiguration();
  }

  private getConfiguration() {
    this.apiService
      .createCartWorkarea(this.queryParam, 'test')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.updateCart(response);
        this.testData = this.store.select('Cart');
        console.log('testData', this.testData);
      }),
      error => {
        console.log('response', error);
      };
  }

  updateCart(response) {
    this.store.dispatch(new shoppingCartAction.LoadCartAddAction(response));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement ngrx v4 to my angular project and struggling with getting data from ngrx store. I wrote Actions, Reducer and tried to select the value dispatched but getting undefined always
    I tried multiple ways to resolve the issue but still I am getting [image]

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
Problem was with

```
forRoot StoreModule.forRoot({ cartreducerkey:  Cartreducer }) and  
     this.store.select('cartreducerkey').subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data),
             this.testData = data
           });
```